# How do I simulate drag and drop in enzyme testcase?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, drag-and-drop, enzyme, jestjs

I am trying to create a test for simulating a dragging of an image into a div. I am clueless on how to achieve this. Any help is much appreciated.

```
it('test drag and drop', () => {
    const app = mount(<App />);
    const loco = app.find('.app img');
    const dropTarget = app.find('.drop-target');
    let mockEvent = { dataTransfer: { type: 'test' } };
    loco.simulate('drag', mockEvent);
    //loco.simulate('dragover', dropTarget, mockEvent);
    //loco.simulate('drop', dropTarget, mockEvent);
});
```

I am trying to simulate the drop event, not sure how to do as 2 elements are involved in it.

Thanks,
Saud

Answer (score 1):

What DnD Component do you use? React-Dnd?
Maybe [this issue](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/issues/453) on Github can help you.
Or maybe [this article](https://reactjsnews.com/testing-drag-and-drop-components-in-react-js) about testing Drag&Drop via Jest.

Comment: I am not using React-Dnd but using plain JS events for drag and drop. I had gone through the article that you have shared. It makes use of ReactTestUtils and not enzyme